# What does mean ARR in the half place in C?

Tags: arrays, c, function-call, integer-arithmetic, subscript-operator

I have code :get_transaltion(&(arr[1/2]) )
The array is of structures that each contain an array of 3 places, which places does the function accept?

I edited the array in the first place in the structure with an array of 3 places and I didn't get what I edited

```
struct vector { 
  float data[3]; 
};
arr[1 / 2u].data[0] = 1 + 0.1;
arr[1 / 2u].data[1] = 1 + 0.2;
arr[1 / 2u].data[2] = 1 + 0.3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the `/` operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second.

Here:

```
arr[1 / 2u].data[0] = 1 + 0.1;
```

`1 / 2u` evaluates to 0. So it's equivalent to writing:

```
arr[0].data[0] = 1 + 0.1;
```

Answer (score 1):

All these statements

```
arr[1 / 2u].data[0] = 1 + 0.1;
arr[1 / 2u].data[1] = 1 + 0.2;
arr[1 / 2u].data[2] = 1 + 0.3;
```

are equivalent to

```
arr[0].data[0] = 1 + 0.1;
arr[0].data[1] = 1 + 0.2;
arr[0].data[2] = 1 + 0.3;
```

because due to the integer arithmetic the expression `1 / 2u` is equal to `0`.

As for this function call

```
get_transaltion(&(arr[1/2]) )
```

then it is equivalent to

```
get_transaltion(&(arr[0]) )
```

That is a pointer to the first element of the array is passed to the function.